# Why does the absolute value of a power series converge to the same limit as the power series?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Power series, if $$\lim_{{k}\to\infty}ka_kx^{k-1}=0$$ for any $x\in(-1,1)$

Why does this imply $$\lim_{{k}\to\infty}|ka_kx^{k-1}|=0$$ for any $x\in(-1,1)$

I would normally show what work I've done to try and solve for myself but in this case I just don't know what to say. It seems obvious that if the limit goes to zero then the absolute value would also go to zero but I don't know how to formally state this. Is there something deeper that I'm not seeing, why would this be useful/important?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x=0\implies \vert x\vert=0$$
By definition of $\vert x\vert$.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{{k}\to\infty}\vert ka_kx^{k-1}\vert =0$?$$$$I am shocked that you ask this question since you even know what is limit...

Comment: I do mean $$\lim_{{k}\to\infty}|ka_kx^{k-1}|=0$$ for any $x\in(-1,1)$ sorry for the confusion.@Tony Ma I have edited the question

Comment: Since $-\vert a-b\vert\le\vert a\vert-\vert b\vert\le\vert a-b\vert$, so$\vert \vert a\vert-\vert b\vert\vert\le\vert a-b\vert$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb R$, so by the defintion of limit, you can proof that $\lim_{k\to\infty}s_n=0\implies \lim_{k\to\infty}\vert s_n\vert=0.$

Answer (score 1):

The map $u\rightarrow|u|$ is continuous. Perhaps, one sees that $\big||\cdot|-|u|\big|\leq|\cdot-u|$.